# MVC 5 Code First adding new database table with UserId

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

So right now my IdentityModels.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Leepio.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        //company
        [Display(Name = "Virkshomedsnavn")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        //company
        public int NrEmployees { get; set; }
        //company
        public string WorkField { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        //Student
        public string University { get; set; }
        public string StudyProgramme { get; set; }
        public int Semester { get; set; }
        public string GraduationDate { get; set; }
        //
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //Student
        public string Skills { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        //Student
        [DataType("date")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Project { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Experience> Experience { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skill { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Education> Education { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Experience> ExperienceOrdered { get { return Experience.OrderByDescending(e => e.EndYear); } }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {

            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Leepio.Models.Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Leepio.Models.NewsletterMails> NewsletterMails { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Skill> Skill { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Leepio.Models.Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Leepio.Models.Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Leepio.Models.Experience> Experience { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Leepio.Models.Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Education> Educations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, through code (migrations), add a new table as an extensions to the user table (AspNetUsers) through code as to when I register a new user with data taken from facebook, the data that I don't need for the main Users Table can go to the second one, lets say call it "FBData" with the appropriate userId.
To put it in perspective:
Register user would add userID, FirstName, LastName, Email to Users table and at the same time add ID and Locale, Gender in the FBData table.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Identity uses AspNetUserClaims to store all additional data you specified in your ApplicationUser model class. When you use external Authentication Provider such as Facebook, Google etc. a new entry is created in AspNetUserLogins table to store the ProviderKey. This key is used when user is logging in to your application for the second time.

For my understanding your plan to create a FBData table is not necessarily good. How about you add Google Authentication after? Will you create a GData table?

The best option would be in your AccountController in ExternalLoginCallback (function triggered when the user is redirected back from your external authentication provider to your page) map what you received from facebook to your ApplicationUser and maybe redirect the the user to the registration form with pre-populated fields to finish the registration cycle. All the trash data you can store if you like in a separate table AspNetUserClaims_External but you have to model it first.

Check:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do. First you can create a FbData class with the properties you need in that table. Then add the properties you need to the ApplicationUser Class. You need the foreign key for the FbData table

```
public int FbDataId { get; set; }
```

and you also need to add the virtual property for the table:

```
public virtual ICollection<FbData> FbDatas { get; set; }
```

Last in your IdentityContext add you DbSet for your table:

```
public DbSet<FbData> FbData { get; set; }
```

Run the application on a clean db to see your changes reflected..

You can also override the OnModelCreating class in your IdentityContext to make any modifications to the Generated Identity Tables.

Comment: It looks like you are putting all your Models in the IdentityModels.cs so you can put it there. However, it's best practice to only have one class per file. FbData would not inherit from IdentityContext though, this is only for your ApplicationDbContext.